# How to make Gmail atom feed show all emails in a conversation, or the last email in a conversation

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, email, gmail, ui-automation

Background: I'm currently trying to use the Gmail Inbox Feed (https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed) in my browser automation script in order to defeat 2-factor authentication. I'm working as a tester and want to bypass the profile creation to get to testing the actual bugs quicker. Basically my script tries to log into my website that has 2-factor authentication, then it gets the latest email using the feed and looks for the token that the website sends.

My problem is that it seems like the feed is only showing the **oldest** email from each conversation. It doesn't show new emails. That won't work for me since my script will trigger a bunch of these emails and they all get grouped into one conversation. And I need the latest email since that is the one that has the token. Curiously, the `<issued>` tag shows the date and time of the newest email even though the email in that containing `<entry>` tag is an old one.

If you want to reproduce this problem yourself: send an email to yourself, then reply to that email with a different message so that both emails show up in the same conversation. Then mark them **both** as unread by clicking the dropdown arrow on the **oldest** email and then clicking "Mark unread from here". If you go to the feed URL above, it will only show the first email you sent to yourself.

Is there a setting or parameter that I can set in order for the feed to show all latest emails? Or at least the **newest** email in each conversation?

I tried turning "Conversation View" off at `Settings > General` but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: this sounds like it could be illegal!

Comment: It's for testing purposes. I'm working as a QA Tester but I need to test everything except the profile creation. But I still need to create them, so I just want to create a bunch of profiles and then get to testing.